# Simplest way to get data from a dynamic HTML table

Tags: javascript, html, simple-html-dom

I am trying to get data from a dynamic HTML table. The user has to option to add or delete rows (through a javascript script) and then enter data into the table input fields. 
I need a way to get the data out of the table. I realize that javascript can not write to a file, but are there any other options?

Thank you kindly. All help is greatly greatly appreciated!

**Edit: I am adding and deleting rows/columns to the table, so the text inputs are dynamically created and I am trying to get the values from those fields.

Answer (score 0):

You could create a simple JS function to fish out data in an array form.
I'm assuming a very simple table for this.
I've used JQuery for ease but you can do the same with javascript..

```
<table id="mytable">
<tr>
  <td>1</td>
  <td>3</td>
  <td>4</td>
  <td>2</td>
</tr><tr>
  <td>5</td>
  <td>6</td>
  <td>7</td>
  <td>8</td>
</tr><tr>
  <td>9</td>
  <td>31</td>
  <td>42</td>
  <td>23</td>
</tr>
</table>
<script>
    getAllDataFromTable();
</script>
```

I've used JQuery for ease but you can do the same with javascript..

```
function getAllDataFromTable(){
    var mydata = Array();
  for(i=0;i<$('#mytable').find("tr").length;i++){
    mydata[i] = Array();
    var currentRow = $('#mytable').find("tr").eq(i);
    for(j=0; j< currentRow.find('td').length ;j++){
        mydata[i][j] = currentRow.find('td').eq(j).html()
    };
  };
  alert(JSON.stringify(mydata))
}
```

https://jsfiddle.net/9yuc3bvj/

Comment: Hi! First, thank you for the answer! I apologize for not being clear.I need to be able to take data that comes from a new td Element created when I add /delete rows to a table.

Comment: you could just use the inner while loop for that. Get the final table row using ($('#mytable').find("tr").length - 1) and traverse through the TDs.